# How to set default currency as GBP for UK and USA customers in magento?

Tags: magento

I have a magento store with multiple currencies. I want to set GBP as default currency for UK and USA customers. I have tried everything but the default currency is still coming as USD even for UK customers. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Magento can't do this by default.

You can either [code your own solution](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-set-default-store-currency-based-on-visitor-country-in-magento/) or look to one of the [third party modules to implement GeoIP and currency allocations](http://innoexts.com/promotion/zone/).